# GitLab CI Manually triggered pipeline executing all jobs irrespective of rules

Tags: gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I am using gitlab ci for my CI pipelines , one of the case is to execute a job when a particular file is changed . But when executed manually by run pipeline option it executed that job also.
Is this default behavior for manual pipeline or some more rules are required.

Job which should be executed only for file change, but getting executed when triggered manually.

```
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building web"
  rules:
    - changes: [ FILEBASE/**/* ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges), when a pipeline it triggered manually `rules: changes` always evaluates as true:

> `rules: changes` always evaluates to true when there is no Git `push` event. Tag pipelines, scheduled pipelines, manual pipelines, and so on do **not** have a Git `push` event associated with them. A `rules: changes` job is **always** added to those pipelines if there is no if that limits the job to branch or merge request pipelines.

So, if you want to exclude this job on manual triggers, you'll need to add an `if:` condition to your existing rule, or add additional rules.